# VB.net Web Browser - Adding Bookmarks

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, browser

I have a web browser that I am trying to keep to the minimal to keep it running fast (I have the firefox gecko browser engine even though that doesn't matter for this question I think.) but there is one thing I want to add and that is bookmarks. Right now I have a ton of messy code but I wasn't able to create a new tool strip button for each time I hit the bookmark button. So what I did is I added the appropriate settings and 6 toolstrip buttons. Now this limits me to 6 bookmarks. Which really sucks. My code is here:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class tabForm
    Dim ico As Image = Nothing
    Private Sub goBack_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles goBack.Click
        webBrowser.GoBack()
    End Sub

Private Sub goForward_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles goForward.Click
    webBrowser.GoForward()
End Sub

Private Sub Navigate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Navigate.Click
    If urlBox.Text = "yt" Then
        webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.youtube.com")
    ElseIf urlBox.Text = "fb" Then
        webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.facebook.com")
    ElseIf urlBox.Text = "gm" Then
        webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.gmail.com")
    ElseIf urlBox.Text = "go" Then
        webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com")
    Else
        webBrowser.Navigate(urlBox.Text)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles webBrowser.DocumentCompleted
    Me.Text = webBrowser.DocumentTitle
    geticon()
End Sub

Private Sub webBrowser_Navigated(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As Skybound.Gecko.GeckoNavigatedEventArgs) Handles webBrowser.Navigated
    Try
        urlBox.Text = webBrowser.Url.ToString

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub urlBox_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles urlBox.KeyDown
    Try
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            If urlBox.Text = "yt" Then
                webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.youtube.com")
            ElseIf urlBox.Text = "fb" Then
                webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.facebook.com")
            ElseIf urlBox.Text = "gm" Then
                webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.gmail.com")
            ElseIf urlBox.Text = "go" Then
                webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com")
            Else
                webBrowser.Navigate(urlBox.Text)
            End If
            e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub geticon()
    Try
        Dim url As Uri = New Uri(webBrowser.Url.ToString)

        If url.HostNameType = UriHostNameType.Dns Then

            ' Get the URL of the favicon
            ' url.Host will return such string as www.google.com
            Dim iconURL = "http://" & url.Host & "/favicon.ico"

            ' Download the favicon
            Dim request As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(iconURL)
            Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
            Dim stream As System.IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
            Dim favicon = Image.FromStream(stream)

            ' Display the favicon on ToolStripLabel1
            Me.favicon.Image = favicon
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.favicon.Image = Nothing
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub favicon_timer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles favicon_timer.Tick
    Try

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Reload_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Reload.Click
    webBrowser.Reload()
End Sub

Private Sub ToolStripButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton1.Click
    webBrowser.Navigate(My.Settings.mark1)
End Sub

Private Sub ToolStripButton6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton6.Click
    webBrowser.Navigate(My.Settings.mark6)
End Sub

Private Sub ToolStripButton5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton5.Click
    webBrowser.Navigate(My.Settings.mark5)
End Sub

Private Sub ToolStripButton4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton4.Click
    webBrowser.Navigate(My.Settings.mark4)
End Sub

Private Sub ToolStripButton3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton3.Click
    webBrowser.Navigate(My.Settings.mark3)
End Sub

Private Sub ToolStripButton2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton2.Click
    webBrowser.Navigate(My.Settings.mark2)
End Sub

Private Sub Fav_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub ToolStripButton7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton7.Click
    If ToolStripButton1.Text = webBrowser.DocumentTitle Then
        ToolStripButton1.Text = ""
        My.Settings.mark1 = ""
        My.Settings.mark11 = ""
        ToolStripButton1.Visible = False
    End If
    If ToolStripButton2.Text = webBrowser.DocumentTitle Then
        ToolStripButton2.Text = ""
        My.Settings.mark2 = ""
        My.Settings.mark22 = ""
        ToolStripButton2.Visible = False
    End If
    If ToolStripButton3.Text = webBrowser.DocumentTitle Then
        ToolStripButton3.Text = ""
        My.Settings.mark3 = ""
        My.Settings.mark33 = ""
        ToolStripButton3.Visible = False
    End If
    If ToolStripButton4.Text = webBrowser.DocumentTitle Then
        ToolStripButton4.Text = ""
        My.Settings.mark4 = ""
        My.Settings.mark44 = ""
        ToolStripButton4.Visible = False
    End If
    If ToolStripButton5.Text = webBrowser.DocumentTitle Then
        ToolStripButton5.Text = ""
        My.Settings.mark5 = ""
        My.Settings.mark55 = ""
        ToolStripButton5.Visible = False
    End If
    If ToolStripButton6.Text = webBrowser.DocumentTitle Then
        ToolStripButton6.Text = ""
        My.Settings.mark6 = ""
        My.Settings.mark66 = ""
        ToolStripButton6.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ToolStripButton8_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton8.Click
    If ToolStripButton1.Text = "" Then
        ToolStripButton1.Text = webBrowser.DocumentTitle
        My.Settings.mark1 = webBrowser.Url.ToString
        My.Settings.mark11 = webBrowser.DocumentTitle
        ToolStripButton1.Visible = True
    ElseIf ToolStripButton2.Text = "" Then
        ToolStripButton2.Text = webBrowser.DocumentTitle
        My.Settings.mark2 = webBrowser.Url.ToString
        My.Settings.mark22 = webBrowser.DocumentTitle
        ToolStripButton2.Visible = True
    ElseIf ToolStripButton3.Text = "" Then
        ToolStripButton3.Text = webBrowser.DocumentTitle
        My.Settings.mark3 = webBrowser.Url.ToString
        My.Settings.mark33 = webBrowser.DocumentTitle
        ToolStripButton3.Visible = True
    ElseIf ToolStripButton4.Text = "" Then
        ToolStripButton4.Text = webBrowser.DocumentTitle
        My.Settings.mark4 = webBrowser.Url.ToString
        My.Settings.mark44 = webBrowser.DocumentTitle
        ToolStripButton4.Visible = True
    ElseIf ToolStripButton5.Text = "" Then
        ToolStripButton5.Text = webBrowser.DocumentTitle
        My.Settings.mark5 = webBrowser.Url.ToString
        My.Settings.mark55 = webBrowser.DocumentTitle
        ToolStripButton5.Visible = True
    ElseIf ToolStripButton6.Text = "" Then
        ToolStripButton6.Text = webBrowser.DocumentTitle
        My.Settings.mark6 = webBrowser.Url.ToString
        My.Settings.mark66 = webBrowser.DocumentTitle
        ToolStripButton6.Visible = True
    Else

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ToolStripButton9_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton9.Click
    Dim newFav As New ToolStripButton
    newFav.Text = webBrowser.Url.ToString
    newFav.PerformClick()
End Sub

Private Sub favClick()

End Sub

Private Sub tabForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If My.Settings.mark1 <> "" And My.Settings.mark11 <> "" Then
        ToolStripButton1.Text = My.Settings.mark11
        ToolStripButton1.Visible = True
    End If
    If My.Settings.mark2 <> "" And My.Settings.mark22 <> "" Then
        ToolStripButton2.Text = My.Settings.mark22
        ToolStripButton2.Visible = True
    End If
    If My.Settings.mark3 <> "" And My.Settings.mark33 <> "" Then
        ToolStripButton3.Text = My.Settings.mark33
        ToolStripButton3.Visible = True
    End If
    If My.Settings.mark4 <> "" And My.Settings.mark44 <> "" Then
        ToolStripButton4.Text = My.Settings.mark44
        ToolStripButton4.Visible = True
    End If
    If My.Settings.mark5 <> "" And My.Settings.mark55 <> "" Then
        ToolStripButton5.Text = My.Settings.mark55
        ToolStripButton5.Visible = True
    End If
    If My.Settings.mark6 <> "" And My.Settings.mark66 <> "" Then
        ToolStripButton6.Text = My.Settings.mark66
        ToolStripButton6.Visible = True
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

That's all of it. But as I said earlier I could only add 6 bookmarks. Is there any way I can add an unlimited number of bookmarks. I tried something like this:

```
Private Sub Bookmark()
  Dim mark As New ToolStripButton
  mark.DisplayStyle = Text
  mark.Parent = ToolStrip1 'This didn't work
End Sub
```

But if I did get that to work what would I put to make it navigate to that page? Please help.

I finally found the answer to this. If anybody wondering where here is the link:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/eebcf40a-dec9-41ae-8e8b-3d446cf93322/web-browser-bookmarks-bar

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

create a class called favorite and a setting called favorites of type system.collections.specialized.stringcollection

```
public class favorite
    inherits toolstripsplitbutton
    public mytitle as string
    public myurl as string
    public myimg as image
    public mybrowser as webbrowser

    public sub new(title as string, url as string, browser as webbrowser)
        mybase.new()

        mytitle = title
        myurl = url
        'create a getfavicon function - Google :)
        myimg = GetFavicon(myurl)
        mybrowser = browser
        me.text = mytitle
        me.tooltiptext = mytitle + " : " + myurl
        me.image = myimg
    end sub

    private sub Favorite_Click(sender as object, e as eventargs) handles me.click
        browser.navigate(myurl)
    end sub
```

then in your form code add a sub

```
public sub AddFav() handles '>>the add favorite button<<.click
    my.settings.favorites.add(webbrowser.documenttitle + "|" + webbrowser.url.tostring)
    my.settings.save()
end sub

public sub RefreshFavs()
    for each fav as string in my.settings.favorites
        dim favarray as array = fav.split(new char() {"|"c})
        dim x as new favorite(favarray(0), favarray(favarray.count - 1, webbrowser)
        mytoolstrip.items.add(x)
    next
end sub
```

simple explanation:

AddFav() - save favorites with page title and url

RefreshFavs() - splits each setting by the "|" which the title and url are seperated

Class Favorite() - allows you to add a splitbutton that navigates the linked browser to it's myurl variable.

hope this helps. sorry if its a little crude, I had to recall it from my memory.

Comment: @Charles here is my answer